# how to set phpMyAdmin 4.2.12 on debian 8.5 as ssl only

Tags: ssl, phpmyadmin

I installed the latest phpmyadmin 4.2.12 on debian 8.5, but it is not on https

so I enabled ssl on apache

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

added

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
```

to

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

but now it does not take my password anymore and it does not force https

anybody knows how to set this up ?

```
dpkg -l | grep phpmyadmin
ii  phpmyadmin                     4:4.2.12-2+deb8u1           all          MySQL web administration tool
```

thanks (let me know if you need more infos)

Comment: pretty obvious is'nt it ? ;-)

Comment: sorry, I meant which OS you have on server machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was to set it up in apache with aredirect or rewrite rule